# Laravel - Adding information to relationship output

Tags: laravel

- I have `users` table
- I have `pets` table
- The relationship between them is `belongsToMany`.
- These tables have pivot table named `user_pets` with information regards a speicifc pet of an user.
- I get the user pets, including the pivot table information using `$user->pets()`. the `pets()` method in my User Model is:

  ```
  public function pets()
  {
     $pets = $this->belongsToMany(Pet::Class, 'user_pets')->withPivot(
      'id',
      'position',
      'level',
      'exp'
      )->orderBy('position','asc');
      return $pets;
  }
  ```
- As you can see, every pet as `level` and `exp` fields. the exp required to get the next level is listed in my `pet_exp` table:

  `ID | level | requiredExp`

  `1   5   237
  2   6   406
  3   7   637
  4   8   942
  5   9   1326
  6   10  1800
  7   11  2369`
- **The problem:** I want to return the requiredExp of the pet's current level  using `$user->pets()` (the method above). I've been thinking for couple of hours and couldn't think of a way how to do it.

Hopefully you can help me, Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking to return, for example, `237` if the pet level is `5`, or do you want to return `406` since that's one level higher than the pets level?

Comment: I'm asking to return 237.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add a property to the `Pet` model? Or do you have to have it in the returned `pets()` array? If I were doing this, I'd likely add a `requiredexp()` function to the `Pets` model which would return the exp required for `$this->level`.

Comment: Yes, it will be acceptable, as soon as I don't need to add a new database field.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

In your `Pet` model add a `requiredexp` function:

```
function requiredexp() {
    return DB::table('pet_exp')->where('level', $this->level)->value('requiredExp');
}
```

This should return the requiredExp for the level of the pet that you call the function on (i.e. `$pet->requiredexp`)

EDIT:

You can also do it as an attribute:

```
function getRequiredexpAttribute($value) {
    return DB::table('pet_exp')->where('level', $this->level)->value('requiredExp');
}
```

Comment: The main problem i'm facing is making it default for all pets using `$user->pets()`. that means that every pet will have this value automically calculated when retriving the user pets. I need to have this value in my relation output.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking, but I think you can do what you're wanting with attributes. I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: I mean that the method I posted in my qusetion, `pets()`, will output the pet required exp for each pet. I've been trying to use `foreach` with no luck.